# Why isn't the function being called in the if statement? (python)

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I have recently begun learning programming and more specifically python. I am a total beginner and I started working on my first small project of converting inches and pounds. I can't figure out why the function isn't being called in the if statement. Please help! Thanks.

```
# Convert inches to centimeters and pounds to kilograms


# Converts inches to centimeters
def convic():
    amti = raw_input("How many inches? **Integers only!** ")
    if amti.isdigit():
        amti = int(float(amti))
        centi = amti * 2.54
        print "%d inches equals %d centimeters." % (amti, centi)
    else:
        print "Sorry that is not a number and/or integer."

# Converts pounds to kilograms  
def convpk():   
    amtp = raw_input("How many pounds? **Integers only!** ")
    if amtp.isdigit():
        amtp = int(float(amtp))
        kilo = amtp * 0.45359
        print "%d pounds equals %d kilograms." % (amtp, kilo)
    else:
        print "Sorry that is not a number and/or integer."

answer = raw_input("Would you like to convert inches to centimeters or    pounds to kilograms? ")   
if answer == "inches to centimenters":
    convic()
if answer == "pounds to kilograms":
    convpk()

# Not a correct response        
else:
    while answer != "inches to centimeters" and "pounds to kilograms":
        answer = raw_input("Sorry please enter inches to centimeters or  pounds to kilograms. ")
        if answer == "inches to centimenters":
            convic()
        if answer == "pounds to kilograms":
            convpk()
```

Comment: You have a lot of if statements, is there one in-particular causing the issue?

Comment: @user3636636 all of the ones that contain convic() or convpk()

Comment: @James my program isn't executing convic() or convpk(), i just can't figure out what i did wrong

Comment: "inches to centimenters": extra n

Comment: @EricLevieil that's it, thanks alot...can't believe i didn't catch that

Comment: out of topic* If you want to get `int`/`float` input from user why you use `raw_input()` and then turn `str` into `int`- use `input()` instead

Comment: Also, [that's not how `and` works.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Comment: @Andersson oh, yeah I'll try that..i didnt know that's what input did so thanks haha

Comment: That is quite a lot to get a user to type in, you might want to reword your input question 'Type [1] for inches to centimeters, Type [2] for pounds to kilograms'. The `if` statements would then also be shorter. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misspelled centimeters as centimenters.
If you correct that then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This line is not what you want:

`while answer != "inches to centimeters" and "pounds to kilograms":`

I suppose you wanted:

`while answer != "inches to centimeters" and answer != "pounds to kilograms":`